Why are governments allowed to take on loans knowing that their successor will need to repay them?
For example, if public polls show that a government will likely lose the next election, then it might be pretty rational for it to take on loans. A lot of them. Then, it could finance welfare spending with it.
Then, if they win the election this way, then well done. If not, their successor - most likely, the current opposition - will need to repay it. The uneducated voters will experience that they lived better under the previous government.
This is the reason that nearly all countries of the developed world are rolling large loans before them (source, pdf), without the real possibility that once it will be paid back.

Excessive debt and policies financed only via borrowing is something that is vocally called out here. What makes you assert that the "uneducated voters" will see just the good? It is pretty easy to call out excessive spending in simple terms and fighting words.

Historically, government borrowing was often done to fund wars, and if you're being invaded you probably think it's more important to win the war than keep the next government debt-free, but that's not really a consideration now for the US or UK. If you're borrowing to build a dam that will take 10 years to construct and will operate for 50 years, it makes sense to schedule repayments over a long period. It's exactly the same as business or personal debt.

The source doesn't seem to relate to elections.

"Why are governments allowed to..."  because they make the laws?

Also, wrt your last paragraph, there's debt forgiveness https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_2000#Impact_on_debt_policy

There's simply no practical alternative. Few governments can afford to fund all necessary programs with cash reserves and current income, debt is a necessary evil. Debt that carries through to successor administrations is simply accepted as part of the system, because the alternative is either unacceptable levels of austerity or increased taxes and tariffs.
In addition, debt is an important part of the global economy. The interest that developed nations pay on their huge amounts of debt is important income to investors and other nations.

About your second point: that is fine, for the investors, but not for the governments. I think the rational behavior for the government would be to not take loan et al, instead invest into others.

We're all part of a global community. If the US stopped issuing debt, it would crash the economies of many of our trading partners, which would impact our economy. We talk alot about the ballooning US debt, but if we wiped it out and ran with a balanced budget, it would actually be a disaster.

Yes it would crash, particularly those whose living is that they give loan to the USA. And? If your work becomes unneeded, wouldn't you be soon fired? Why would USA be nice to these guys, USA should be nice to its tax payers and citizens.

No, the debt should be paid back, and should not be taken next time. If there is no hope to pay it back, yes that is a disaster.

Much of our economy depends on exporting to other countries. If they can't buy our stuff, we lose that revenue. Only strict isolationists believe we can go it alone.

That is fine, having commerce with other is wonderful. Taking loans from others only because that is usual, I think that is not fine.

The point is that we're stuck in this system now. Kind of like how the banking industry is dependent on the fact that many people are heavily into debt on their credit cards. If everyone paid their cards off every month, banks would go out of business, and then we couldn't get credit cards. It's a vicious cycle.

USA is specific case, there is another problem, interest payment grows with the loan together. As the loan grows, there will be a point where USA can not pay back even the interest. That is not fine with 6000 ICBMs in the backstore. I have no idea, what to do. Maybe a constitutional amendment to prevent similar cases in the future as today, that could help.

That's theoretically why Congress has to approve raising the debt ceiling every year, to prevent it from getting out of hand. But they also know that it's not realistic to stop raising it, we can't feasibly balance our budget.

Just because the current government is going to lose an election doesn’t mean that the loans are not needed and necessary. In the end governments are expected to take action for the good of the people regardless of expectations of winning or losing an election.

Yes that is expected from them, but I can not see, why would they lose an election to do what is expected from them. There is a known phenomenon that tax increases, unpopular decisions tend to happen after the election, and popular decisions before it.

@GraySheep Because not everyone wants to screw over the next government when they lose an election.

You say that parties in normal countries have some type of mutual trust that they do not utilize all possible black tricks against the other?

@GraySheep Isn't that how a democracy is supposed to work where governments do a smooth transition from one government to the next? Just because they lost in this election doesn't mean that they won't win in the next on.

Government borrowing is normal and a part of the economic system of even the most successful nations. It's not a dirty trick governments are pulling on voters (although sometimes it may be excessive). Borrowing to fund infrastructure is virtuous, because the increased productivity and economic activity should cover the loan payments - that's how businesses and governments try to do it.

@StuartF Yes, getting loan for welfare expenses just before the election, yes that is a dirty trick. It is not an economy theory thing, it is basic human ethics. That is I am talking about, not in general about the government loans which are ordinary economical decisions, and... you know it...

@JoeW That is much better and I believe, it depends on some like a "nash equilibrium" among the top parties of a political system. Just not doing things useful on the short-term, because it would lead to a world no one wants, that is okay. Next step will be to know, what is exactly happening in some better known countries with a high and growing debt/gdp rate, like USA or Japan (but afaik also UK has problems)
